# Encrypting my data and keeping it safe in Unity

Tags: encryption, unity3d

I have a RPG kit in the Unity Store and I wanted to add some protection for the consumers for when they want to save pretty much any information.  From the gear the character is wearing to inventory, bombs, keys, locations where objects were moved etc.  I already have all that working it is just I was using the Unity C# serializer but ran into the issue when I deserialize when I add more to the class that holds the saved information.  So I used JsonUtility, I turned the saved class into Json data and was going to put it in PlayerPrefs but I wanted to offer some extra protection for the consumers so I looked into AES and Asymmetrical Encryption.

This is my quick run down and as of now for when I save my data :

1) I generate a random string for my "Key" with AES.
2) I Symmetrically Encrypt my data (AES).
3) I then Asymmetrically Encrypt the AES "Key".
4) Store the Asymmetrically Encrypted "Key" and the AES encrypted data in PlayerPrefs.

I feel though since I stored the Asymmetrically Encrypted "Key" in PlayerPrefs that it still holds the same amount of security as if I was to just store the random generated AES "Key" in PlayerPrefs as the key is there for any reversal process.

Am I correct in thinking this?  Is there a step I am missing or need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start off with a slightly dickish response, namely, if you are uncertain about this stuff you should focus on finding a (reputable) library that will handle these sorts of things for you.  I'm not all that familiar with Unity, so if such a library exists, I hope someone else can provide an answer pointing to it.  As I'm sure you are aware, even major corporations mess these kinds of things up.

That said, I don't really understand from whom you are trying to protect this data.  (I also don't understand why this would be sensitive but that's not important.)  As far as I can tell the PlayerPrefs are stored locally so the kinds of attackers you are considering are 1) other applications on the device, 2) other users on the device, 3) attackers with physical access to the persistent memory e.g. the SD card.  Most of these are already protected against via operating system mechanisms.  But to be completely clear, doing encryption yourself *will* increase protection beyond what the operating system is doing.  The argument comes down defining a [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model) and doing the cost-benefit analysis of mitigating the threats.  The cost-benefit analysis will include the development and maintenance costs for you, and the key management costs for the user, e.g. if the user loses their key, they lose their data and *nothing* can be done about it.

Addressing your second to last paragraph, if you just stored the symmetric key with the encrypted data you would have no security.  You might as well store the unencrypted data.

Your four step scheme should work (though there are details you need to get right), but it seems to be overkill.  If the symmetric key is encrypted, then I'll need to have access to the private key to decrypt it.  If I can securely store the private key, why don't I just store the symmetric key where I store the private key?  Alternatively, unless it is a large amount of data, why not just encrypt the data directly with the private key?  Or even, if I can store keys securely, why don't I just store the data there?

I only see something like your four step procedure being useful if the asymmetric keys are managed by the OS but no symmetric key management is provided, and you need to encrypt large amounts of data.  In fact, decent crypto libraries will usually handle automatically generating a symmetric key and storing it encrypted with the ciphertext so you don't have to worry about it and you don't need to worry about size limitations or performance.

Comment: Hey Derek,

I didn't think that response is dickish at all.  I am severely ignorant and really trying to understand encryption and trying to figure out if its right for the RPG kit I am working on. I realize that for single player games you shouldn't worry if the user happens to alter file data but I want to eventually have my rpg kit work with mobile/online and I felt (this is my ignorance speaking here) I would need to keep the data safe. I have only ever made single player games and was going to slowly adapt my rpg kit to be mobile/online and figured having secure data was the way to go.

Comment: Unless you are providing higher than normal security, you should not need to directly deal with encryption. There will likely only be two areas where encryption will be happening behind the scenes. Storing credentials and transferring data over the wire.  The former is usually completely and transparently handled by authentication frameworks. The latter is typically handled by HTTPS/TLS and requires you getting a server certificate and configuring your server to use it. There may be some code you need to support this, but it certainly won't be at the level of calling encryption routines.

Comment: In online env, the security is provided by the protocol (ssl). So It's going to be encrypted at this point. How to prototect yourself from "users" hacking the files (PlayerPrefs) could be matter of validations rather than encryption. I have played many mmo (Desktop) and almost all of them have property files that can be edited with Notepad. Thing is that these files are restored during the login. After the login any change is validated at server side.

Comment: @DerekElkins So pretty much my worry about the data being manipulated is worrying over nothing?  Like you said the 2 areas I should consider encryption would be credentials (ID and password I would presume) and transferring data over the wire (Have not done yet but I think I have an idea what you mean).  So (talking more of an online perspective) I wouldn't really care about the stats the player had when they disconnected/quit as I can take Laiv answer and do Idempotence (like from a database on server side)?

Comment: @Laiv check my response to Derek.  Is this on the right track of what you meant?

Comment: That's the common way to work with today's client-server applications. You left the encryption to the protocol (https) and by server design you grants the correctness of the input data. Once Game is running, the security is implented by **authorization** and/or **authentication**. Also ny desing. Some server-side designs are harder to hack or to trick.

Comment: The kind of encryption you were asking about,makes sense when you need to grantee that the message is going to be accessible only by a limited number of targets (persons,systems,etc..). It's not your case.

Comment: @Laiv Thank you so much for taking the time to help out my ignorance on this matter.  I honestly feel like a kid in classroom having fun learning about something so I just want bombard you with questions haha.  Thanks again as now I can start to continue my project with less ignorance and more confidence.